# Compiling Geary for Windows

Tags: compilation, vala

I would like to compile the Linux-based mail client, Geary, for my Windows computer.

I'm wondering if I could compile it using a program such as MonoDevelop on my Linux machine with the target being Windows, or if I'll have to use cygwin or mingw on my Windows machine.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a former Geary developer, and I tried doing this about a year ago.  Geary itself ought to compile fine, but not all the dependencies are Windows-friendly.  Also, getting WebKit to build is non-trivial.

Answer (score 4):

You can cross compile on Linux to Windows. There is a MinGW build for Linux. Use `valac -C` to produce C sources then `i586-mingw32msvc-gcc` to compile the sources and link against Windows DLLs of the libraries needed. Vala determines includes using `pkg-config` which will pick up compilation arguments from the host system. You can override this by setting `PKGCONFIG_PATH` to the directories where your Windows libraries' `.pc` files live.

Comment: I tried the "valac -C" command, but it just threw out a bunch of errors about missing symbols/files. When I went to the mentioned source files, it did the same thing, until it just gave me a simple "Compilation failed" error. Any suggestions?

Comment: `valac -C` doesn't link, so I don't know how ther ecan be missing symbols. You'll need to post more details. Try the Vala IRC channel.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to compiling, you can run Geary on Windows 10 via the WSL.
This question here lead to give it a try. It can be done, but requires many steps and it doesn’t work very well for the time being.

https://heracl.es/ephemera/2018/08/08/geary/

Answer (score -3):

Do you really need to compile it? If you have windows 10, you can run a linux environment, for instance ubuntu. Then Geary runs. I can confirm, as I have it running NOW.

There are several tutorials on how to get Ubuntu running in the WSL on Win10.

Comment: I'd be great if you could share your steps on how to do this. Unfortunately `apt-get install geary` alone won't do it, as it complains for xserver issues.